# Dredd Api Blueprint for text format

Tags: apiblueprint, dredd

There is an api blueprint dredd test problem which bothers me for a while.

I can dredd test json format successed, but for text format, it always be failed.

```
The fail message -> fail: body: Real and expected data does not match.
```

But I check the body of expected and real are the same.

Can anyone help me or give me some suggestions? I am very appreciate.

**The following is my code :**

```
### Get counting camera [GET]

+ Response 200 (text/plain)

+ Body

      vadp_module_number='3'
      vadp_module_order='1,2,0'
```

**The following is dredd test result :**

```
fail: body: Real and expected data does not match.

expected:
headers:
Content-Type: text/plain

body:
vadp_module_number='3'
vadp_module_order='1,2,0'

statusCode: 200


actual:

statusCode: 200
headers:
    date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 14:09:39 GMT
    server: Boa/0.94.14rc21
    accept-ranges: bytes
    connection: close
    content-type: text/plain
    cache-control: no-cache
    pragma: no-cache
    content-length: 4856

body:
vadp_module_number='3'
vadp_module_order='1,2,0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your body is not correctly indented.

**camera.md**

```
FORMAT: 1A

HOST: http://127.0.0.1:5000

# Camera

The camera is a simple API allowing consumers to manage your security cameras.

## Camera [/camera]

### Get counting camera [GET]

+ Response 200 (text/plain; charset=utf-8)

    + Body

        vadp_module_number='3'
        vadp_module_order='1,2,0'
```

I test it with Drakov mock server and Dredd and it runs well.

**[Drakov](https://github.com/Aconex/drakov)**

```
drakov -f ./camera.md --public --watch --discover
```

Or [run it with docker](https://gist.github.com/asantos2000/6d11deb47960fc7488bd44663161a766).

**[Dreed](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd)**

**dreed.yml (fragment)**

```
...
hooks-worker-handler-port: 61321
config: doc/examples/dredd.yml
blueprint: doc/examples/camera.md
endpoint: 'http://localhost:5000'
```

And run with:

```
dredd --config ./dredd.yml
```

Or run [dredd with docker](https://gist.github.com/asantos2000/9043e7466d873bf4bd46a57651ccc1c3) too.

Results in

```
info: Configuration './dredd.yml' found, ignoring other arguments.
2018-06-25T17:30:23.883Z - warn: Parser warning in file 'camera.md': message-body asset is expected to be a pre-formatted code block, every of its line indented by exactly 12 spaces or 3 tabs on lines 17-18
2018-06-25T17:30:23.884Z - info: Beginning Dredd testing...
2018-06-25T17:30:23.920Z - pass: GET (200) /camera duration: 34ms
2018-06-25T17:30:23.920Z - complete: 1 passing, 0 failing, 0 errors, 0 skipped, 1 total
2018-06-25T17:30:23.921Z - complete: Tests took 36ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In combination with API Blueprint, Dredd can fail on a trailing newline with text/plain bodies. See [apiaryio/dredd#67](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/issues/67).

See the [Remove trailing newline character in expected plain text bodies](https://dredd.org/en/latest/hooks/js.html#remove-trailing-newline-character-in-expected-plain-text-bodies) section in Dredd's docs for a workaround:

```
var hooks = require('hooks');

hooks.beforeEach(function(transaction) {
  if (transaction.expected.headers['Content-Type'] === 'text/plain') {
    transaction.expected.body = transaction.expected.body.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
  }
});
```